# How do I execute the setup.exe installer for WindowsServer2019 from a command/powershell?

Tags: windows-server

I did a stupid thing and upgraded my Windows server to server2019 and chose non gui mode by mistake.
I know the drive letter of the .iso (on a usb stick) is L: and can see the iso but I don't know how to actually execute the setup.exe

I tried sconfig and the option to swtch is not there, because I didn't install it when I ran the upgrade from the iso

Comment: This might be applicable: https://debug.to/248/convert-from-windows-server-2019-core-to-gui

Comment: Thanks - so I am not going crazy! Is there any way to access the setup.exe from the actual ISO in theUSB drive, or do i have to make my USB drive bootable, add the ISO and start from scratch?

Comment: I ended up making a bootable USB with Rufus and then had to shift to the command prompt and repartition/format the boot drive as GPT